# Build a matrix or a list for equations in R in a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, types, equation

I want to calculate a Seemingly Unrelated Regression model. But I don't wan't to code every single regression equation in R. I wan't to fill a matrix or a list with the equations in a loop. I thought in this way: for (n in ..)

```
SURmatrix[n,1]<-lm(esfirm.w[,n]~esmarkt.w[,n])
```

and the fit the model in this way:

```
fitsur <- systemfit(SURmatrix[,1])
```

but the problem is, that the type of "formula" isn't compatible with a matrix.

has anyone an idea to solve this problem?